# Get Ethereum to run on a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: raspberry-pi

How would one get Ethereum to run on a raspberry pi zero?

Comment: This question is too broad. Could you specify which part you don't understand, e.g., space limitiations, or architecture issues, or compiling with low resources available?

Answer (score 4):

The Raspberry Pi Zero might not have enough resources (memory/disk/cpu) to download the entire blockchain and be used as a full node. If you just want to use it for generating accounts (maybe as part of a cold wallet), you could:

1. [Go to the go-ethereum v1.3.3 release page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.3) (or whatever is currently stable)
2. Download "geth-ARM-20160105140454-1.3.3-c541b38.tar.bz2" on your
   Raspberry Pi Zero
3. Untar. `tar -xvf geth-ARM-20160105140454-1.3.3-c541b38.tar.bz2`
4. Run `geth` as you would normally at the console. (`geth account new` for instance.)

If this doesn't work (I'm not sure on the compatibility between ARM architectures with various rPIs), you may need to [custom compile it](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum).

Comment: Ethereum is available in the [Arch User Repositories](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=ethereum). Easier than compiling.

Comment: @5chdn I didn't see an ARM binary on that page.