# Can Ethereum be pruned to the extent that it could be run from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: light-clients, state-trie-pruning, raspberry-pi, android

What are the limits to how much the ETH blockchain can be pruned. Will ETH ever be practical on devices with limited resources such as a Raspberry Pi, Android or iOS wallet?

Comment: Possibly of interest, though specific to RPi Zero: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/845/52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Light clients are on the way for lower power embedded devices. I believe these light clients only get block headers initially, and further data as needed on-demand from full nodes on the Ethereum network. Here are 2 of the light clients that are work-in-progress I am aware of:

[Official Ethdev Light Client](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)

[Ethcore's Parity](https://ethcore.io/parity.html)

In regards to pruning the blockchain, it [looks like that is coming in geth v1.5](https://twitter.com/jeffehh/status/724911668959055874).