# Can Ethereum or Mist run on Raspberry Pi 1, 2, 3, or Zero?

Tags: mist, light-clients, raspberry-pi

Would an ethereum client or mist be able to run on a raspberry pi?

It's a simple yes or no question with an explanation. I don't want links to "light" versions of ethereum, as that's not what I'm asking for. And second of all they do not even exist yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Ethereum be pruned to the extent that it could be run from a Raspberry Pi?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4151/can-ethereum-be-pruned-to-the-extent-that-it-could-be-run-from-a-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Not really a duplicate IMO. But Raspberry Pi is not the most straightforward platform to use with ethereum so you'll probably have to wait to get an answer. Be patient.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/raspberry-pi-support-on-ethereum/12458#12458

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although Geth has always worked on the RPI, we haven't put much effort into optimizing for such low end devices. During the Olympic testnet I did make Geth syncable on the RPI1, but there have been quite massive modifications and it wasn't a priority to keep this platform operationally feasible.

We're currently in the midst of releasing Geth 1.4.6, which will mostly be a networking fix to allow lower end connectivity peers to stably sync, but after this, work will commence on various database optimizations to make lower end devices feasible again. I can't say how low we'll manage to go, but I would definitely like to see RPI2 at least capable of running a full node.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it but apparently you can (link below) !!

[diyEthereumGeth](http://raspnode.com/diyEthereumGeth.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @5chdn Sorry, I didn't know Sir, I am new :), the reason I did copy and paste as it's very long.

Answer (score 2):

There's a really excellent ongoing effort over at http://ethembedded.com/ to build images for boards like the Raspberry Pi. They're all homestead compatible.

Not sure if these count as "light" by your definition.

They have geth/eth/parity builds available for:

- Raspberry Pi 2/3
- Odroid XU3/XU4
- WandBoard Quad
- BeagleBone Black

Check them out and happy hacking!