# Raspberry Pi v3B support on Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, raspberry-pi

We are in the starting phase of Ethereum and Raspberry pi. I came to know from documentation that Ethereum supports Raspberry pi v2. I just wanted to know whether it supports Rasbperry pi v3 model B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. I started to write a procedure a couple of weeks ago in [here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/blockchain_exploration/blob/master/ethereum/infrastructure/README.md) based on [ethraspbian](http://ethraspbian.com). 
It works fine.